# Delete an analytics region from my Apigee Paid Organization

Tags: analytics, apigee

I am struggling to delete the analytics region from my Apigee Paid organization

I have found the following code

```
DELETE https://apigee.googleapis.com/v1/{name=organizations/*/analytics/datastores/*}
```

But not sure where/how to run this. It is failing from the API explorer

Thanks

Comment: You are referring to an 'Analytics Region' but your code involves Apigee Analytics Datastores, which are specifically for use in exporting analytics from Apigee. What is your goal?

Docs:
https://docs-analytics.apigee.io/data-store-api

The proper URL syntax for deleting an (export operations) Apigee Analytics datastore entity is:
https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/organizations/org_name/analytics/datastores/uuid

In the Apigee Management-API regime best is to start with successful GETs before moving on to POSTs, and then DELETEs. Q: Can you perform a GET call on the target entity?

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by deleting the Organization and provisioning from scratch. There is no way to change the Analytics region, so don't choose the wrong one!